# Python comparing a column of a dataframe with a numerical and producing an output

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe as given below:

df =

```
           result 
0       -43.859440
1       -20.000000
2        63.666667
3       116.500000
4       -22.333333
5        12.500000
6      -103.705882
7       322.800000
8      -513.888889
9       774.000000
10    -4508.000000
```

I want to produce another column called `count` consisting element 1 if a value in corresponding row `result` is >0 and -1 if less than zero.

My current code:

```
df['count'] = [1 if df['result']>0 else -1 if  df['result']>-1]
```

My present output:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My expected output:

df =

```
           result         count
0       -43.859440          -1
1       -20.000000          -1
2        63.666667           1
3       116.500000           1
.
.
```

What could be wrong in my present code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where()`. See below:

```
import numpy as np
df['count'] = np.where(df['result']>0,1,0)
```